# Receive inbound sms from Twilio on Joy of Texting Pro Plugin.

Tags: twilio

I am trying to integrate twilio with the Joy of Texting Pro WP plugin. How do I setup Twilio to send inbound sms to the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [documentation for the Joy of Texting Pro has some details on how you setup inbound SMS to the plugin](http://www.getcloudsms.com/documentation/pro-settings-tab/#jot-inbound).

You need to log in to your Twilio account and [edit the number](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming) you are using to receive messages on. You need to enter a URL in the Messaging section for when a message comes in. From what I can tell, you need to use your WordPress application's URL plus `?inbound`. e.g `https://mywordpresssite.com?inbound`

Let me know if that helps at all.